# Mouse Over animation with JackHammer image

Tags: javascript, image, onmouseover, onmouseout

so I'm working a small problem here. I manage to get the animation to play once the you move over the image with the mouse, but it keeps going through it. I have 10 images total, so the longer you keep your mouse over the image, the more images that appear. If you remove the mouse then it stops at whatever image it stopped on. I just need it to go to the last image being image 10 and stop there, maybe even reset back to image 0.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var curJackhammer = 0;
var begin;

function bounce() {

document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'jackhammer' + curJackhammer + '.gif';
curJackhammer ++;

if (curJackhammer > 10) {
    curjackhammer = 0;
}

} // end of bounce funntion

function startBouncing() {
if (begin) {
    clearInterval (begin);
}  // end of if statement
begin = setInterval(bounce,90);
} // end of start bounce function

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Jackhammer Man</h2>

<img src="jackhammer0.gif" onMouseOver="startBouncing();" onMouseOut="clearInterval(begin);" alt="Jack Hammer Man" />

</body>
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this

```
function endBouncing() {
  clearInterval(begin);
  curJackHammer = 0;
  bounce();
}
```

And then set your `onMouseOut` handler to `endBouncing()`

Comment: Sorry I guess I'm not clear @CharlesBahena Did this work out, or is there some further issue?